# Why is the format 'HH:mm' not working in this DatePipe?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to display a `Date` object in an `input` field and only display the minutes

```xml
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="time" placeholder="Choose a time" 
       [(ngModel)]="appointmentTime"
       [ngModel]="appointmentTime  | date:'HH:mm'"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, the time is not getting displayed correctly - not at all in fact:

[image]

In the class, `appointmentTime` and `appointmentDate` are initialized as

```js
public appointmentDate = new Date();
public appointmentTime = new Date();
```

Comment: Have you registred the pipe as provider? Are the round brackets missing in ngModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use ngModel twice, this should work ,

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="time" placeholder="Choose a time" 
       [ngModel]="appointmentTime  | date:'HH:mm'"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9esrjg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Dangit .. that was indeed the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input matInput type="time" placeholder="Choose a time" 
       [ngModel]="appointmentTime  | date:'HH:mm'"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.